# Flutter background task in iOS crashes app

Tags: ios, flutter, background-task

In release mode, when I run my app, if I have the app in the background for around 30 seconds and bring the app to the foreground I get the error-log:

```
2020-07-24 23:12:14.473633+0200 myTest[11229:3284265] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2020-07-24 23:12:14.608936+0200 myTest[11229:3284265] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
2020-07-24 23:13:06.713676+0200 myTest[11229:3284265] dnssd_clientstub read_all(15) DEFUNCT
2020-07-24 23:13:06.713798+0200 myTest[11229:3284265] [VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(131)] Could not register as server for FlutterObservatoryPublisher. Check your network settings and relaunch the application.
2020-07-24 23:13:06.733470+0200 myTest[11229:3285031] [] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-07-24 23:13:06.733962+0200 myTest[11229:3285031] [] nw_read_request_report [C5] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-07-24 23:13:06.734091+0200 myTest[11229:3285031] [] nw_read_request_report [C4] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-07-24 23:13:06.734177+0200 myTest[11229:3285031] [] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-07-24 23:13:06.738494+0200 myTest[11229:3284531] dnssd_clientstub write_all(40) DEFUNCT
2020-07-24 23:13:06.738517+0200 myTest[11229:3284531] dnssd_clientstub deliver_request ERROR: write_all(40, 65 bytes) failed
2020-07-24 23:13:06.738540+0200 myTest[11229:3284531] dnssd_clientstub write_all(40) DEFUNCT
2020-07-24 23:13:06.742580+0200 myTest[11229:3285031] [] nw_read_request_report [C5] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-07-24 23:13:06.751339+0200 myTest[11229:3285031] [] nw_read_request_report [C4] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
```

This will result in a grey-screen, freezing the app. Any idea what is causing this error or how to get around it?

I'm using firebase, maybe this is causing it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, do you find a solution for that ?

Comment: Are you tired of this one, by adding the following methods in the app delegate 

 override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    }
    
    override func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    }